# Why is it difficult to use a linear regression model for the classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear-regression

Why is it difficult to use a linear regression model for the classification problems? [image]

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim? I’m interested in the exact phrasing and context.

Comment: Do you have a reference from a standard credible source like a textbook, journal article, or even a post by an accomplished researcher (something on Stack Exchange, Twitter/X, etc) or a course website? // I’ve never heard of “Hole House” and don’t want to click that link.

Comment: @Dave No, contents in the post based on the free Coursera Machine Learning course.

Answer (score 1):

Because linear regression makes predictions based upon linear and continuous data. Classification involves nonlinear (usually) and discrete data.

In regression, we are typically predicting the next number (or set of numbers) in a sequence. If we want to know the rainfall in inches next week, we can feed a regression algorithm the historical rainfall data for our area.

In classification, we are typically *classifying* objects. Is this image a dog, or a cat? We can feed our classification algorithm images of dogs and cats, and then, when we give it an image, it will tell us if that image contains a dog or a cat.

In your image, we can see that trying to fit a linear trend line to discrete data produces a line that does not capture the majority of our outputs. Your input data is not linear or continuous, so if you use regression, you should expect your model to have very poor accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

For classification, we generally want the output to be between 0 and 1, to be able to interpret it as a probability. As show in your graph a linear regression can go to +/- infinity, well outside of the (0,1) range. For example how would you interpret a -1 outputted by the model here ?

It is not that bad if you are interested in relative ranking. As is, a linear model would give you a good AUC for exemple. But the model would not be calibrated in probabilities.

The other problem that is visible on your graph is that the linear regression would be more sensitive to outliers. The line change significantly with (blue) and without (pink) the last outlier, while a logistic regression would mostly be determined by the interface between points with (y=0 and y=1).